# Can't save to Drive > All changes can still be found from File > Version history

Tags: google-drive, google-docs

While working in a Google Docs document I was going through various internet connection problems which eventually lead to most actions being unavailable (like downloading the file). In addition to that, I have a warning saying

> Can't save to Drive
>
> All changes can still be found from File > Version history.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to solve it, I opened Google Drive in a new tab and ensured to be able to see all files and folders in the root. I couldn't see that right away and had a message with a "reconnect" button. Clicked in it, then I've gone back to the document and everything was working fine again.